# how to select only one column value with more than one with same names only by using where condition?

Tags: sql

How to select only one column values without using functions first , last , top , limit in a table ?

Want to use only where command:

```
ename  age

hansen  25

hansen  25

hansen  25
```

How to select only one values hansen 25 ?

in the above table

Answer (score 1):

Then use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ename,  age
FROM TableName;
```

**Update:** If don't need to use `DISTINCT`, then you can do the following if you are using sql server:

```
SELECT ename, age
FROM 
(
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ename DESC) AS row, *
    FROM RableName
) sub
WHERE sub.row = 1;
```

### [Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/74617)

Comment: without using distinct want to use only where condition?